# Calculating midpoint of two times

Tags: php

```
Sunrise: 6:50am
Sunset:  4:45pm
```

How do I calculate the mid-point of these two times? By calculating manually, I know its approx `11:47am`, but not sure how to do it programatically.

Comment: Convert them to timestamps, take the average, convert back.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth `date('H:i:s', ((strtotime($sunrise) + strtotime($sunrise)) / 2))` ? It returns `06:50:00`

Comment: @3zzy https://eval.in/385122 What the values you set to suntimes?

Comment: @splash58 Heck! My code is exactly the same as yours, but it returns `06:50:00` for some reason. https://eval.in/385125

Comment: No, you are using `$sunrise` two times

Comment: Darn! I'm so stupid. :p

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth actually my answer is nothing else but I calculate to timestamps not in seconds since 1.1.1970, but to timestamps in minutes since daystart, as that matches the problem better. It would be better for all of us if we sometimes think about the meaning of timestamps and the resolution they carry. A signed int32 timestamp will overflow @`2^31 / 86400 / 365=68` apporximately 68 years since 1970 somewhere in 2038. Not too far away.

Comment: @ikrabbe: Sure, but your approach will require manual parsing of the input strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not actually a php question and actually you don't need any date functions. Just use some mathematics

```
1h = 60min
am = 0min
pm = 12*60min
```

so

```
Sunrise = 6*60min + 50min = (360 + 50)min = 410min
Sunset = (4+12)*60min + 45min = (960 + 45)min = 1005min
```

the mid-point is `(Sunrise+Sunset)/2 = 1415/2 min = 707.5min`

```
(707 / 60) = 11h    (integer division!)
707-660 = 47min
```

there you go: 11:47 (and 30 seconds ;))

*As long as you don't need days, months and years, you will get much happier with pure mathematics.*

Answer (score 0):

you can use the explode method

$sunrise = 6:50

$sunset = 4:45

$time1 = explode(":",$sunrise);

$time2 = explode(":",$sunset);

$the_hours = $time1[0] - $time2[0];

$the_min = $time[1] - $time2[1];

goodluck.

Comment: `$the_hours = ($time1[0]+$time2[0])/2; $the_min=($time1[1]+$time2[1])/2;`. You forgot the `am` and  `pm` and you loose precision.